# File uploader error: File Not Found

Tags: control-panel, file-uploads

When I try and upload images to my EE site (either from my file manager or from a file field in the channel entry form on the CP), I get a "Error: File Not Found" message. The file gets uploaded to my server, but the database doesn't have an entry for the upload.

Any thoughts on what is going on and/or how to debug the issue?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I fixed my issue by removing file upload definitions from my config file. I used the config file to modify upload directories in different environment (local development, staging and production). Now I just manually keep the upload directories by editing the corresponding table in the database.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I also use the config file to manage upload preferences after some hours of debugging I realised that the upload path was missing the trailing forward slash “/“ this resolved the problem I was having.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issues here. I'm setting my url and directory paths in a config file but was missing the trailing slash as mentioned above on my path. I should note, my issue was happening on a IIS server.

Didn't Work:

```
http://www.website.com/images/uploads/blog/
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\images\uploads\blog
```

Worked: (notice unix style trailing slash on path)

```
http://www.website.com/images/uploads/blog/
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\images\uploads\blog/
```